# TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python-3.9

On this code:

```
##script qui brute force les hashs

import hashlib

while True :
    try : 
        wordlist_user = input("entrez votre wordlist:  ")
        wordlist = open(wordlist_user, "r", encoding='utf-8')
        hash = input('entrez le hash que vous oulez cracker (sha224) : ')
        break

    except :
     print('Error')



for word in wordlist.readlines():
    word = word.strip()
    wordlist_hash = hashlib.sha224(word).hexdigest()

    if (hash == wordlist_hash):
        print('password trouve: ' +word)
    else :
        print('password non trouve')
```

**I have this error**

wordlist_hash = hashlib.sha224(word).hexdigest()
TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing

**can someone help me ?**

Answer (score 13):

`hashlib.sha224()` takes bytes but `word` is a string. You'll want to convert the string to the utf-8 encoded bytes with `word.encode(encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'strict')`

Comment: btw `errors = 'strict'` is the default